# Undefined reference error with OpenCV in Codeblocks for Windows

Tags: c++, opencv, gcc, cmd, undefined-reference

I have installed Opencv for codeblocks and the program runs well in codeblocks. But  when I try to run the program from command prompt,I get an error as `fatal error:opencv2/opencv.hpp No such file or directory compilation terminated`

So I ran the command as

```
g++ -IC:\opencv\build\include -o main.exe main.cpp
```

And I get many undefined reference errors.I have even tried to link the libraries as

```
g++ -IC:\opencv\build\include -LC:\opencv\build\x86\mingw\lib -o main.exe main.cpp
```

Still I get same errors.I use Opencv 2.4.5.I did not use -l option since there are many libraries and I dont know how to link all those libraries(directory) at once.

This is the compile output.

```
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x6d): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xb7): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::convertTo(cv::_OutputArray const&, int, double, double) const'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x152): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::zeros(int, int, int)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x322): undefined reference to `cv::noArray()'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x384): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x3bd): undefined reference to `cv::meanStdDev(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x5c7): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x5ea): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x645): undefined reference to `cv::resize(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::Size_<int>, double, double, int)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x665): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x685): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x6d6): undefined reference to `cv::threshold(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, double, double, int)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x705): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x752): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::convertTo(cv::_OutputArray const&, int, double, double) const'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x775): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x7c2): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::convertTo(cv::_OutputArray const&, int, double, double) const'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x7e5): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x808): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x828): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x86e): undefined reference to `cv::inpaint(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, double, int)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x89e): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x8be): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x910): undefined reference to `cv::resize(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::Size_<int>, double, double, int)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x92a): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x971): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::convertTo(cv::_OutputArray const&, int, double, double) const'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xc68): undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(std::string const&, int)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xcee): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xd3f): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xd8c): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::convertTo(cv::_OutputArray const&, int, double, double) const'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xe05): undefined reference to `cv::operator-(cv::Scalar_<double> const&, cv::Mat const&)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xe6b): undefined reference to `cv::operator+(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xebb): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xede): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xf2f): undefined reference to `cv::threshold(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, double, double, int)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xf74): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xf97): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xff2): undefined reference to `cv::resize(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::Size_<int>, double, double, int)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x103d): undefined reference to `cv::operator*(cv::Mat const&, double)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x105d): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::MatExpr const&)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x10b8): undefined reference to `cv::imwrite(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1110): undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv3MatD1Ev[__ZN2cv3MatD1Ev]+0x2d): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv3MataSERKS0_[__ZN2cv3MataSERKS0_]+0x102): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv[__ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv]+0x3e): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZNK2cv3MatclENS_5RangeES1_[__ZNK2cv3MatclENS_5RangeES1_]+0x23): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::Mat(cv::Mat const&, cv::Range const&, cv::Range const&)'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv12_OutputArrayC1IdLi4ELi1EEERNS_4MatxIT_XT0_EXT1_EEE[__ZN2cv12_OutputArrayC1IdLi4ELi1EEERNS_4MatxIT_XT0_EXT1_EEE]+0x21): undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_OutputArray'
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ccraot3b.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv11_InputArrayC2IdLi4ELi1EEERKNS_4MatxIT_XT0_EXT1_EEE[__ZN2cv11_InputArrayC2IdLi4ELi1EEERKNS_4MatxIT_XT0_EXT1_EEE]+0xe): undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_InputArray'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Please add the compile output to the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I did not use -l option since there are many libraries and I dont know how to link all those libraries(directory) at once.

You have to use the `-l` option for each library that must be linked. There is no GCC commandline
option that means *link whatever libraries are in this directory*. The `-L` option as in your `-LC:\opencv\build\x86\mingw\lib` does not mean that. It means *search in* `C:\opencv\build\x86\mingw\lib` *for any libraries that are requested by the* `-l` *option*. But if you don't request any libraries
with the `-l` option then none will be searched for.

When you build your program in Code::Blocks, the compile and link commands that are executed are printed in the **Build log** tab (*not* the **Build messages** tab). So if you look in the build log you will see exactly what `-`-options must be passed to the compile command and then to the link command. Use exactly the same options, in the same order, at the command prompt and you will build the program in exactly the same way.

Comment: @sai To build complex software using lots of commands and long command lines, we usually use a higher level commandline tool called [`make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/). Here's a [tutorial about GCC and Make](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html) You'll find a Windows port of `make` comes with your mingw GCC distribution. It's called `mingw32-make.exe`. Code::Blocks uses `make` internally to build your projects. Nowadays an even higher level tool called `CMake` is very popular too.
`CMake` also uses `make`, so it's better if you understand `make` first.

Comment: Ok I will look into it.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Likely problem is, you are using backslash in paths. If you are compiling with MinGW or Cygwin (and I suppose you are), then in that shell, backslash is an escape character. So if you want plain backslash, you usually have to escape it: `\\`. However, that's not the right solution for your problem. You should use normal slash, `/`, in paths:

```
g++ -IC:/opencv/build/include -o main.exe main.cpp
```

and

```
g++ -IC:/opencv/build/include -LC:/opencv/build/x86/mingw/lib -o main.exe main.cpp
```

Comment: Normal slash did not work.I have added the compile output.